# Unresolved DotNetCore capability in demands of octopus tasks for build process

Tags: .net-core, azure-pipelines, octopus-deploy, azure-pipelines-build-task

We are using some steps on our build pipeline that push nuget packages to octopus and create an Octopus release. 
Somehow these tasks alter the demands of the agent phase, so that it requires "DotNetCore" to exist as a capability on the build agent.

The yaml of the phase looks like this:

```
queue:
name: Default
dependsOn: 
- Phase_1
- Phase_2
condition: succeeded()
demands: DotNetCore
```

We use self-hosted build agents, on machines that actually have .Net core installed. But DotNetCore doesn't show up in the capabilities. Guess we can add it manually, but not sure what would be the value to provide for it. Guess we could simply add the folder of the .Net core installation as value.

But again, didn't find anything documented somewhere, and adding capabilities manually without knowing what value to add feels like a hack.

Is there any way to get rid of this demand?

Comment: Are you sure you have installed the [.NET Core SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/sdk) on the agent machine? If you haven’t already got the .NET Core SDK installed on your build server(s), follow the [.NET Core installation guide](https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/get-started-with-dotnet-tutorial) for your OS. Remember to install the version your application targets. After that, just try to restart the agent services or reboot the build server, then check it again.

Comment: If that still not work, just try to add a  `.NET Core Tool Installer` task to install the tool first. Reference this thread : https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/800#issuecomment-397228820

Comment: Thank you.. so far adding the capability manually solved the issue. But I will try if installing the SDK (again) would work as well. Adding the installer task I think is not the preferred solution, if it installs the SDK for every single build. We want to keep the time of the builds as low as possible, especially since Microsoft changed to only allow 1 active build on premise for free.